# put free points

Tags: pgfplots

I have this:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
Label,x,y,angle
a,0,0,90
b,2,2.5,90
c,3,2.9,90
d,4,4,-90
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xlabel= $Interes$, ylabel=$Power$,
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=left,
visualization depends on = \thisrow{angle} \as \angle]
\addplot +[only marks,
        nodes near coords=,
        point meta = explicit symbolic,
        every node near coord/.style = {
            anchor = center, pin = {\angle:\pgfplotspointmeta}
        }
    ] table
  [col sep = comma, x = x, y = y, meta = Label
  ] {\jobname.csv};

  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
```

This is the result:

[image]

I want the move the point a of 0,0 (cordinates) -> to 1,1

```
a,1,1,90
```

But the code do this:

[image]

?????

I want do this:
[image]

any ideas?
thank you very much

Comment: `xmin=0,ymin=0`, add to the `axis` options.

Comment: yes!!!! thank you very much!! One more thing! Do youw know how to remove the numers of axis x and y (remove 1,2,3,4) thanks!

Comment: If you want to remove the ticks (the small lines) as well `xtick=\empty,ytick=\empty`, if you just want to remove the ticklabels (the numbers), `xticklabels={},yticklabels={}`.

Comment: By the way, use `xlabel=Interes`, or if you want italics, `xlabel=\textit{Interes}`. It's a word, not a mathematical construct, so don't put in in mathmode (`$ ... $`).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in the comments.